# Notepad++: What does "Mac" format do?

Tags: notepad++

Under `Settings > Preferences > New Document > Format`, there are 3 options: **Windows**, **Mac**, and **Unix**. I have looked on the Notepad++ Help pages, but it seems they're outdated, the images still referring to past versions with a different Preferences page UI.

I'm just wondering what the "Mac" option does. I'm running Windows 7 Professional, SP1 (64 bit)

Answer (score 33):

The options refer to how newlines are handled—whether with a carriage return (CR), line feed (LF), or both.

- Windows: `CR LF` (`\r\n`)
- *nix/OSX: `LF` (`\n`)
- Mac (pre-OSX): `CR` (`\r`)

This can be relevant when scraping docs, writing regexes, sharing data between applications, etc.

Comment: Do note that this is **classic** Mac OS. **Mac OS X** would use Unix-style line endings due to its Unix heritage.

Comment: For development compatibility (Git and whatnot) it would be better to choose the the Unix option, correct?

Comment: @kel it doesn't matter what you use, so long as it's consistent and that no one changes it. Most editors nowadays can recognize and adapt to whatever style your document uses.

Comment: @Seiyria An important exception being the text editor that comes with Windows: Notepad. Wordpad can handle Unix line endings, but Notepad cannot. When programs designed on Linux are ported to Windows, sometimes the documentation will be text files in Unix format, and it's all jumbled up on one line in Notepad. This one thing is why Notepad++ is my default text editor, even when I don't need most of its features.

Comment: @kei On Windows, Git, by default, will normalize line endings for you (commit Unix-style, checkout Windows-style).

Comment: @meatspace, Giulio Muscarello: So it doesn't make the UI more "Mac-ish", right?